# Updating files and starting jobs on a cluster with a script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cluster-computing

I'm using the cluster of my university for some computations. Currently I upload the files with WinSCP to the cluster and then I'm using Putty for starting the jobs (bsub command).

Is it possible to write some script which first checks if there are new or changed files and if so, uploads them to the cluster and then starts the job/jobs? I'm using windows.

Edit: An option is also to delete the folders and re-upload them (there are small files). This should be possible with scripts I think.

Comment: Using a Windows equivalent of rsync might be the right tool for the job: http://serverfault.com/questions/35336/why-hasnt-rsync-caught-on-in-the-windows-world

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).